# Need help installing driver

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

There seem to be two ways to install the printer driver for the Canon 530.

1. Download the file Linux_UFRII_PrinterDriver_V320_us_EN.tar.gz from Canon; untar it; go to install the printer; point the printer at the PPD file in the untarred folder.  Problem:  I find no PPD file in the untarred folder.
2. Go to localhost:631; ADD a printer; click on the Canon D530 which the computer has found; identify the Canon D530 as made by manufacturer Canon; pick the model of the Canon D530 from the very long dropdown list of models.  Problem:  the Canon D530 is NOT on the list of Canon printers, although the list does include maybe 200 or more different Canon printers.

I'm still pretty new to Ubuntu, and I like it, but I'm not sure what to do next.  There's probably something obvious that I'm missing.  Help, please!

Comment: Which printer are we talking about? This office laser printer: [Canon D530](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/d530)?

Comment: Yes, the Canon D530.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I picked up at their official [site](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/d530#DriversAndSoftware) with this you should be able to see it in cups:

1. Download the printer drivers [here](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/d530#DriversAndSoftware)
2. extract it and then move it to `/home` directory
3. open your terminal in the *extracted folder*

   [image]
4. run `sudo ./install.sh` and follow the command prompt
5. Go to cups console in a browser `http://localhost:631/admin` and add your printer

Hope it helps

Comment: Hope it went well ?

Comment: Thanks, George.  

I have followed these five steps, and I get to the stage where the drop down menu wants me to check the model number.  I don't know why; it has already identified that the printer is the Canon D530.  But it wants what it wants.

I've taken a screenshot, but askubuntu doesn't seem to want to let me post it.  It shows the dropdown model menu, and shows that there's nothing between the Canon CP 330 and the Canon E 400.

Comment: Hence the driver for D530 is missing?

Comment: I don't know.  I downloaded the linux file provided on the Canon website, on the page for the D530.  I assume the file is right and I'm doing something wrong.  I suppose it could be that for some reason the file could be wrong.

Comment: Did you restart your system?

Comment: I did. This appeared to make no difference for the drop-down:  there was not a D530 on the dropdown when I tried it before, and still is not.

Comment: Try printing a document and see if the printer will appear and print.

Comment: In a document, the print function identifies only my previous printer; there is no listing for the D530.  Going to the printers function to Add a new printer, it immediately finds the D530, looks for a driver, fails, and brings me to a table with options to choose Generic, or some manufacturer; when I choose Canon, it gives me what appears to be the same drop-down list of 200 ish models to choose from.  The D530 does not appear on that list.

Comment: Try the generic driver

Comment: Also, I should note that booting into Windows, I was able to download and install windows drivers for the D530 without problem.  After installing the drivers, the D530 printed documents properly.  So it does not appear to be a problem with the printer itself.

Comment: When I use the generic settings, it fails to print a test page, and fails to print page from a document, saying "Could not start printer.  Please check your printer configuration."